# Power or Energy Signal of x(t) = u(t)

Tags: signal-analysis, continuous-signals

Is $x(t)=t \cdot u(t)$ a power signal or an energy signal?

Please "show" me why - preferably using equations.

Comment: This question would do so much better with you showing your attempt. Your question is *very* basic, and it's really hard to see what you're missing to answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the energy of a continuous signal you use the equation: 
 $$E_\infty = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} |x(t)|^2 dt$$  
 and for the power:  
 $$P_\infty = \lim\limits_{T\to\infty} \frac{1}{2T}\int\limits_{-T}^{T} |x(t)|^2 dt$$ 
 If your signal has finite power ($0<P<\infty$) then it's a power signal. If the signal has finite energy then it's an energy signal (Notice that a signal can be neither type but can't be an energy and a power signal at the same time).

Comment: I am able to calculate the energy and show that it's infinity. I am having trouble calculating the power. I know that this signal is neither a power signal nor an energy signal but I get a finite value for power. (1/24)*T^2.

Comment: I think you made a mistake while calculating the integral. And where did your limits disappear (when T goes to infinity so does your final result).